# How to construct an xpath to click the logout link as per the html provided

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to click on the logout link to log out of the application using selenium xpath. The web page has user image link and when it is clicked a drop down for Logout link is displayed. When I try to locate the xpath of the Logout link, it does not go anywhere. Any thoughts,  please ?

Here is my page source for that element. Don't know if this gives any idea.

```
<div data-v-5fa222fc="" class="user"><!----> <a data-v-5fa222fc="" class="user-menu">QA@some.com &nbsp; <img data-v-5fa222fc="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....uQmCC"></a></div>
```

Comment: Probably the the html is only there when you click on the down arrow button?

Comment: What do you mean *"does not go anywhere"*? You get exception or just nothing happens?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when I right click on the element, it highlights the <body> tag but not the element path, as if the element is not there at all.

Comment: @9009 Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Comment: I am using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the user image you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the next desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the solutions:

- `partialLinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("QA@some.com"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.user a.user-menu img[src*='data:image/png;base64,']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='user']//a[@class='user-menu']//img[contains(@src,'data:image/png')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much - I am able to click the link of the user profile and see the "Logout" link but unable to click the Logout link. 
So, when I click the user profile link : "QA@some.com", a drop down is displayed and that has "Logout" link. Clicking the Logout link, the application logs out. But inspect element points the <div> tag of the html. It won't point to the path of the element.

Comment: @9009 Can you please raise a new question with your new requirement . Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Sure, adding another one.

Comment: I have added a new question. Here is the link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148289/unable-to-click-the-html-logout-link

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

```
//a[contains(., 'QA@some.com')]
```

Comment: I just tried it, It doesn't recognize the element. I have tried this way

"//img[contains(@src,'image/png')]" and your way, both are failing.

Comment: Does element visible when you try to interact with it?

Comment: The image does not even get clicked by it. My script has .click tied to this element, to click, when it is visible. However, the solution does highlight the element in the page source.