# Unable to click the html logout link

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have a web application which has a profile image link. In order to see the logout link (to click), user profile link needs to be clicked.
I am able to click the profile link and see the "Logout" link but unable to click it. Clicking the Logout link, the application logs out. But inspect element points the div tag of the html. It won't point to the path of that element.

Here is the element path :
profile link ('QA@some.com') --> Logout (where Logout is a link in user profile dropdown)

```html
<div data-v-5fa222fc="" class="user"><!----> <a data-v-5fa222fc="" class="user-menu">QA@some.com &nbsp; <img data-v-5fa222fc="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....uQmCC"></a></div>
```

```html
<div data-v-3b02d5d6="">
<div data-v-5fa222fc="" data-v-3b02d5d6="" id="nav">
<div data-v-5fa222fc="" class="inner"><img data-v-5fa222fc="" width="160" src="/static/img/root.4513063.png" class="logo"> 
<div data-v-5fa222fc="" class="right"><div data-v-5fa222fc="" class="user">
<!----> <a data-v-5fa222fc="" class="user-menu">QA@root.com &nbsp; <img data-v-5fa222fc="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...AElFTkSuQmCC"> 
<span data-v-0af99e56="" class="qa">QA</span>
</div> <div data-v-0af99e56="" class="latest">
<div data-v-0af99e56="">  
          Last build: <span data-v-0af99e56="">2.0</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> <div data-v-0af99e56="" class="box">
    <div data-v-0af99e56="" class="actions">
    <button data-v-0af99e56="" class="std">Deploy</button>
    </div> <!----> 
    <table data-v-0af99e56="" class="clusters"><tr data-v-0af99e56=""><th data-v-0af99e56=""></th>
    <th data-v-0af99e56="" class="bb">Cluster</th> 
    <th data-v-0af99e56="" class="bb">Latest</th> 
    <th data-v-0af99e56="" class="bb">Config Rev</th> 
    <th data-v-0af99e56="" class="bb">Release Date</th> 
    <th data-v-0af99e56="" class="bb">Short Description</th>
    </tr> 
    <tr data-v-0af99e56="">
    <td data-v-0af99e56=""><input data-v-0af99e56="" type="checkbox"></td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">QA2</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">2.0</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">2</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">June 21, 2018 - 4:24 PM</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">Some .jar files added</td></tr>
    <tr data-v-0af99e56=""><td data-v-0af99e56="">
    <input data-v-0af99e56="" type="checkbox"></td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">QA1</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">1.0</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">3</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">June 21, 2018 - 2:50 PM</td> 
    <td data-v-0af99e56="">latest build</td>
    </tr></table></div></div> 
    <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!----> <!---->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The HTML resembles to the user _icon/dropdown_ of `QA@some.com`. I think you are trying to click on the element with text as `Logout`. Please inspect the the webpage and update the question with relevant HTML

Comment: It would be great if you can share more detail, the HTML block of dropdown ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have added a few blocks of code of HTML. I hope this will give some clue. I have tried to see if I can click the element with text, but wasn't working. Is it allowed to attach the screen capture here ?

Comment: @DebanjanB - We as a team struggled to get this to figure what is needed to be done to logout using xpath/stylesheet. Thank you very much - the HTML text link worked finally. The test failed though it is HTML element with text link even after multiple tries, but worked after making some trivial Java code changes.